# Extracting fields from JSON fields from mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to extract all these places mentioned in "location" field and does not want the other fields in the below json.but can't be able to extract since it is nested..Can anyone help me?

```
    DBCursor cursorTotal = coll.find(obje);

    while (cursorTotal.hasNext()) {

        DBObject curNext = cursorTotal.next();

        System.out.println("data::"+curNext.get("list.myList.location");
   }
```

My "curNext" gives output as::

```
    {
    "_id": {
    "$oid": "51ebe983e4b0d529b4df2a0e"
    },
    "date": {
    "$date": "2013-07-21T13:31:11.000Z"
    },
    "lTitle": "Three held for running CISF job racket",
    "list": {
    "myList": [
        {
            "location": "Germany"
        },
        {
            "location": "Geneva"
        },
        {
            "location": "Paris"
        }
    ]
    },
    "hash": -1535814113,
    "category": "news"
}
```

I want my output as

```
Germany,Geneva,Paris
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @BetaRide i have updated my question and added one of my trial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been in a long wait here for an answer and finally I got what I was searching for...Just noting my answer so someone else can benefit from it

```
  DBCursor cursorTotal = coll.find(obje);

    while (cursorTotal.hasNext()) {

    DBObject curNext = cursorTotal.next();

            String res=curNext.toString();
           JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(res);
            JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
            jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("list");
            JsonArray jarray = jobject.getAsJsonArray("myList");
            jobject = jarray.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            String result = jobject.get("location").getAsString();


            System.out.println("all places::"+result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding only locations you should used mongo [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/), below query will fetch all lcoations array

```
    db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$ner.nerList"
},
{
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "location": {
        "$push": "$ner.nerList.location"
    }
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
    "location": "$location",
    "_id": 0
    }
})
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to convert this in Java but, I find below   links which helpfull to you for converting above query in java format 
[Mongo Java aggregation driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/)